# Как сделать так, чтобы калькулятор работал при вводе данных в одну строку?

Tags: java

пример работы как хотелось бы:

Input:
1 + 2

Output:
3

сейчас работает:

Введите число:
1

Введите число:
1

Введите операцию:
+

Результат операции: 2

```
import java.util.Scanner;


class Calculator {
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    RomeNumbers rome = new RomeNumbers();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num1 = getInt();
        int num2 = getInt();
        char operation = getOperation();
        int result = calc(num1, num2, operation);
        System.out.println("Результат операции: " + result);
    }

    public static int getInt() {
        System.out.println("Введите число:");
        int num;
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            num = scanner.nextInt();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Вы допустили ошибку при вводе числа. Попробуйте еще раз.");
            scanner.next();//рекурсия
            num = getInt();
        }
        return num;
    }

    public static char getOperation() {
        System.out.println("Введите операцию:");
        char operation;
        if (scanner.hasNext()) {
            operation = scanner.next().charAt(0);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Вы допустили ошибку при вводе операции. Попробуйте еще раз.");
            scanner.next();//рекурсия
            operation = getOperation();
        }
        return operation;
    }

    public static int calc(int num1, int num2, char operation) {
        int result;
        switch (operation) {
            case '+':
                result = num1 + num2;
                break;
            case '-':
                result = num1 - num2;
                break;
            case '*':
                result = num1 * num2;
                break;
            case '/':
                result = num1 / num2;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Операция не распознана. Повторите ввод.");
                result = calc(num1, num2, getOperation());//рекурсия
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130788/java-string-calculator/29760041

Comment: у меня только два числа

Comment: вы ссылку вообще открывали? Прямо в первом ответе и написан ответ для вашего вопроса. Там не важно сколько у вас чисел, вы передаете в метод строку, т.е. ваше математическое выражение, а он возвращает его результат.

Comment: Этот ответ?

If you want the result 41 for input string "5+20+5+11", why not use ScriptEngineManager with JavaScript engine,

public double calC(String input) {
    int result = 0;
    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();    
    ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");        
    return (Double)engine.eval(input);
}
But note that the return type is double here.

If you want only int as return type in this case, try with this

return new BigDecimal(engine.eval(input).toString()).intValue();

Comment: Да, именно этот ответ.

Comment: да, но я не понимаю на таком уровне, я правильно понял что это уже готовый калькулятор?